# How to use espresso for testing a 3rd party app

Tags: android-espresso

I have recently started working with Espresso and have used it for testing a few apps i have developed and it worked amazingly well. Now as part of work i was supposed to automate a 3rd party app ,say ,for example, the imdb app for android, with the following sample scenario-  (the prerequisite being that i have downloaded the imdb apk file and installed the app on the target phone)

1) Launch the imdb app (from a phone that already has the app installed)
2) log into the app using credentials for an account that has been manually created previously by me (i.e the tester)
3) perform few actions (such as searching for movies, actors etc)
4) log out

From what little understanding i have of espresso i had assumed that it was designed ONLY for developers to test their OWN apps and not third party apps (please correct me if i am wrong !). Plus i couldnt find helpful material online as well. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Espresso is based on Instrumentation and Instrumentation is able to access only one target package, so you can perform actions as long as current activity belongs to target package. Once you open 3rd party app test is over and is going to fail with next action. Answering your question, you cannot use Espresso for testing a 3rd party application. Still you can use other frameworks for that - UIAutomator or Appium.

Answer (score -1):

These instructions should work for espresso as well: https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles

You need to resign the APK you want to test ( I.e. App under test, e.g the IMDB app ) with your dev key and set the target package in your instrumentation APK to point to the app under test ( IMDB ).

Then you will probably want to use something like uiautomatorviewer to inspect the UI under test for IDs, etc.